# Attribute Error when running collectstatic for Django app

Tags: django, gzip, boto, django-compressor, django-storage

I'm receiving the following error when I run collectstatic:

```
AttributeError: 'cStringIO.StringO' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Everything works fine until I try and gzip my files using storages "AWS_IS_GZIPPED" setting (see my settings.py below).

I am using django-storages which utilizes boto to send my static files up to S3 and django-compressor to compress them.

Here is a full traceback of my error:

```
Copying '/home/somewhere/current/something/shows/static/skin/jplayer.band.css'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/somewhere/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/somewhere/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/somewhere/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/somewhere/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/somewhere/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/somewhere/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 89, in handle_noargs
    self.copy_file(path, prefixed_path, storage, **options)
  File "/home/somewhere/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 202, in copy_file
    self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
  File "/home/somewhere/current/something/storage.py", line 28, in save
    self.local_storage._save(filename, content)
  File "/home/somewhere/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 190, in _save
    for chunk in content.chunks():
  File "/home/somewhere/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 65, in chunks
    counter = self.size
  File "/home/somewhere/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 39, in _get_size
    elif os.path.exists(self.file.name):
AttributeError: 'cStringIO.StringO' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Here is my storage.py

```
class CachedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class('compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage')()

    def save(self, filename, content):
        filename = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(filename, content)
        self.local_storage._save(filename, content)
        return filename
```

which comes straight from the [django-compressor docs](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote-storages/).

I also have the following in my settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'something' 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'something_else' 
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'something' 
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'static.example.com' #without this compressor points to my s3 bucket, I serve from CloudFront
AWS_IS_GZIPPED = True #If this is false, everything works, but no gzipping!
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False #turns off https for static files (necessary)

import datetime
future = datetime.datetime.now() #+ datetime.timedelta(days=364)
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Expires': future.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'),
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=60, public' #'max-age=31536000, public'
}

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'something.storage.CachedS3BotoStorage' 

from S3 import CallingFormat
AWS_CALLING_FORMAT = CallingFormat.SUBDOMAIN

COMPRESS_ENABLED = True #can remove when ready for production
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True 
COMPRESS_URL = 'http://static.example.com/'
COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'something.storage.GzipCompressorStorage'
COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR = 'compressed_static'
COMPRESS_ROOT = '/home/somewhere/static'
```

Any help would be much appreciated. A bit lost in the woods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/issues/100 has a proposed work around.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem this way:

The problem is use the same [parameter **content**] to save local and to upload to S3. Because when we passing the parameter content to super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(name, content), internally the parameter **content** is modified, so when passed to next .save _self.local_storage.*save(name, content)* he is with other state due the conf AWS_IS_GZIPPED, that compress the file inside of **content**. 
To fix this simply create one copy of content parameter.

In settings.py

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'mypackage.s3utils.CachedS3BotoStorage'
```

in mypackage.s3utils.py

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from compressor.storage import CompressorFileStorage
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
import copy

class CachedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    """
    S3 storage backend that saves the files locally, too.
    """

    location = 'static'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

    def url(self, name):
        """
        Fix the problem of dont show the natives images django admin
        """
        url = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).url(name)
        if name.endswith('/') and not url.endswith('/'):
            url += '/'
        return url

    def save(self, name, content):
        content2 = copy.copy(content) #-> THE SECRET IS HERE
        name = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(name, content)
        self.local_storage._save(name, content2) #-> AND HERE
        # print id(content)
        # print id(content2)
        return name

    def get_available_name(self, name):
        if self.exists(name):
            self.delete(name)
        return name
```